# Sort dynamic model with orderby

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller, sql-order-by

I am combining 2 tables that I transferred to the dynamic model into 1 table in the cshtml part.

And I want to sort that table by a column(OrderBy). How can I do that? I will be glad if you help.
(Stackoverflow is pushing me to write more text, but I don't know what more to say about this topic. How can I fix?)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GAdiSoyadiSirala()
    {
        var person = db.Personeller.ToList();
        var girisCikis = db.GirisCikisTarihleri.ToList();
        //person = person.OrderBy(x => x.AdiSoyadi).ToList();


        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.Personel = person;
        mymodel.GirisCikis = girisCikis;

        
        return View("GirisCikislar", mymodel);
    }


//The part where I call the GirisCikislar view
public ActionResult GirisCikislar()
    {
        var person = db.Personeller.ToList();
        var girisCikis = db.GirisCikisTarihleri.ToList();


        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.Personel = person;
        mymodel.GirisCikis = girisCikis;
        return View(mymodel);
    }
```

**GirisCikislar.cshtml:**

```
    @using PersonelTakipMVC.Models;
    @model dynamic

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>

    <th>PersonelID</th>



    @*<th>Adı Soyadı</th>*@
    <th>
//When I click this button, the GAdiSoyadiSirala method works.
        @using (Html.BeginForm("GAdiSoyadiSirala", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <button class="btn">Adı Soyadı</button>
        }
    </th>


    <th>Tarih</th>
    <th>Giriş/Çıkış</th>


</tr>


<tbody>

    @foreach (var gc in @Model.GirisCikis)
    {
        <tr>
            
            <td>@gc.PersonelID</td>

            @foreach(var p in @Model.Personel) {
                if(gc.PersonelID == p.PersonelID) { 
                <td>@p.AdiSoyadi</td>
                    break;
                }
            }

            <td>@gc.Tarih</td>


            @if (gc.GirisCikis == 0)
            {
                <td>Giriş</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>Çıkış</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of solving this problem using dynamic I did it using linq.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).